# Returning id in generic insert using JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jooq

I have a very generic API to insert stuff using JOOQ to soem tables:

```
 void insert(@NonNull final Table<?> table,
                @NonNull final Collection<Field<?>> columns,
                @NonNull final Collection<Object> values) {
        dslContext.insertInto(table)
                .columns(columns)
                .values(values)
                .execute();
    }
```

Is there a way to return id of that inserted record? All primary keys of tables in my db are named "id" so I could ahrdcode it but I cannot find a way to return it and cast to Integer / Long. 
I'm using JOOQ 3.9.5.

EDIT: I use MSSQL underneath.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write:

```
long insert(@NonNull final Table<?> table,
            @NonNull final Collection<Field<?>> columns,
            @NonNull final Collection<Object> values) {
    return dslContext
          .insertInto(table)
          .columns(columns)
          .values(values)
          .returningResult(table.field("ID")) // Replace with your field name case
          .fetchOne()
          .into(long.class);
}
```

This assumes you're using generated code whose generated `Table` instances implement `Table.getIdentity()`. Alternatively, if you cannot provide an identity, you could write:

```
long insert(@NonNull final Table<?> table,
            @NonNull final Collection<Field<?>> columns,
            @NonNull final Collection<Object> values) {
    dslContext
          .insertInto(table)
          .columns(columns)
          .values(values)
          .execute();
    return dslContext.lastID().longValue();
}
```

Comment: I'm getting NPE: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at com.xxx.db.rest.app.crud.CrudRepository.insert(CrudRepository.java:48)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)



FYI: I create table from pure string using DSL.table(String sql)

Comment: I'm not using generated code - creating table with DSL.table(String sql) and then working on it.

Comment: @ohwelppp: I see, then you're out of luck with this approach. jOOQ needs the identity information attached to your table, on `returning` calls. See: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2943. You could, however, use `DSLContext.lastID()`: https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#lastID--. I'll update my answer

Comment: With using lastID() is it possible that at the same time some other record is inserted 
 via this api (we have many isntances) and will return that other ID or it get ID() within that context so I'm sure I will return the ID of that inserted record?

Asking because I have to make sure I return correct ID instead of one that was saved by other api instance at the same time

Comment: @ohwelppp: `lastID()` executes a query that fetches `@@identity`. You can use a different SQL Server feature manually, if `@@identity` doesn't suit your requirements.